# Infusionsoft Payment Api - How to check if any subscription failed?

Tags: php, infusionsoft

I am working on infusion soft payments subscription API's and subscription is working fine.Now i need to change the status of user if payment fails in any month but did not get any api related to that.I am using these api for subscription.

```
$subscriptionId =    $app->addRecurringAdv($cid,false,23,2,2.95,true,1,$ccId,$affId,0);
$invoiceID = $app->recurringInvoice($recurringOrderId);

$result = $app->chargeInvoice(16,"API Upsell Payment",2,1,false);
```

Comment: You would need to make calls to API accessible tables using **DataService** **query()** or **findByField()** methods. I personally do not collect information you need (and Infusionsoft API always has some not very well documented specifics),  but would take a look at JobRecurringInstance, RecurringOrder and Invoice tables data first of all.